# How do I reset a Roland D-20?

Tags: synthesizer, keyboard

I wanted to know if there was any way I could reset a Roland D-20 back to all its original settings.

Comment: Not a novice to synths and midi and sysex files but this one is stumping me.
Just got a Roland D10 from eBay for a good price to add to my collection but I have a problem. I have managed to dump and save all the presets but as the performance patches are all mixed up to hell I wanted a clean fresh start. The trouble is it won't let me do a factory reset.
Pressing Tune/Function and Write while turning it on is doing nothing what so ever.
I changed the internal battery and even reseated the Intel chip and still nothing.
Confused to hell totally
Any help would be great.
Even tried leaving the bat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Roland D-20 can be reset by following this procedure:

> HOLD TUNE/FUNCTION AND WRITE WHILE POWERING ON.

According to a [synth reset guide page.](http://www.dlse.nl/synthrepair/reset.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you need the factory patches, they exist as .MID files here:

http://www.rolandus.com/support/downloads_updates/eula.php?FileName=factorypatches.zip

You can dump them into your D20 with any freeware MIDI sequencer and a MIDI interface.